# DjangoRestFramework - How to properly do validation and respond with status codes + error messages when using `get_queryset()`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my view:

```
class PostListByUsername(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SpillSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsLikeOrOwnerDeleteOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if user.userextended.location != self.request.user.userextended.location:
            content = {'Post': ['You cannot view the posts of a user who is not from your location.']}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        return Post.objects.filter(owner__username=username)
```

The problem is, when I enter the `if` statement and try to return the Response, Django raises an error saying:

```
ContentNotRenderedError at /post/username
The response content must be rendered before it can be iterated over.
```

Note that `/post/username` is what calls `PostListByUsername`. With that said, what's the correct way to do validation and return status codes with error messages when inside the `get_queryset()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a `Response` object from `get_queryset` to handle errors -- it must return a queryset (surprisingly).

But, you can raise an `APIException` and it will be wrapped in an appropriate response. You can look at `APIException` and its sublasses [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#api-reference).

While you can do different checks in `get_queryset`, I think in your case it would be more appropriate to put it somewhere else -- for example add your own permission class (where you won't have to raise any exceptions at all) like this:

```
class IsFromSameLocation(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'You cannot view the posts of a user who is not from your location.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        username = view.kwargs['username']
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        return user.userextended.location == \
                   request.user.userextended.location

#...

class PostListByUsername(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = SpillSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsLikeOrOwnerDeleteOrReadOnly,\
                          IsFromSameLocation,)

    #...
```

or do it in a `list` or `retrieve` method.

Adding a custom permission is a cleaner way because it becomes reusable so you can add it in other views.

Generally, common sense hints that you must do exactly what it says in `get_queryset` and raise corresponding exceptions if you can't.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. It looks like the PermissionDenied exception is what I need. With that said, is this how I am supposed to use it in my `get_queryset()` method: `if user.userextended.location != self.request.user.userextended.location:
            raise PermissionDenied({"Post":"You cannot view this list of posts"})`?

Comment: @user2719875 I added detail.

Comment: @user2719875 Also to your comment: yes, something like this but better do it in the `list` or `retrieve` instead of `get_queryset`.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, it works great. Lastly, is this how it would be done in the `list` method (asking just so I can verify if I have a proper understanding): `def list(request, *args, **kwargs): >>>username = view.kwargs['username']  >>>userProfile = User.objects.get(username=username) >>>if request.user.userextended.location != userProfile.userextended.location: raise PermissionDenied({"Post":"You cannot view this list of posts"}) >>>else: self.get_queryset(username)`?

Comment: @user2719875 yes something like this will do.